# How to sum and group a table by a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sum

I have a database like this:
Question table:

```
QId | Title
----------
1   | SR
4   | TR
9   | AA
```

Answer table:

```
RId | QId
----------
2   | 1
3   | 1
5   | 4
6   | 4
7   | 1
8   | 4
```

Vote table:

```
PubId | Type
-------------
2     | P
3     | N
3     | N
1     | P
1     | N
5     | P
4     | P
2     | N
2     | P
```

I want to calculate the score of every question. The score of a question is the difference between positive and negative votes on that question and all of its answers. For example the score of question 1 (with answers as 2, 3 and 7) with QId of 1 is -1 because it hase 3 positive votes and 4 negative votes.
So far I can only calculate the score of a given question. The code is:

```
SELECT P+N FROM (
SELECT sum (case WHEN Type='P' then +1 else 0 end) as P,
sum (case WHEN Type='N' then -1 else 0 end) as N
from ( 
SELECT v.Type from Vote v where v.PubId in (
SELECT r.RId FROM Answer r WHERE r.QId=4
UNION
select q.QId from Question q where q.QId=4)
)
)
```

How can I calculate the score of every question and then sort them from the question with the highest score to the question with lowest score?

The result that I want is 4 (with the score of +2), 9 (with the score of 0), 1 (with the score of -1).

Comment: What does `pubid` refer to?

Comment: How do you define positive vote and negative vote. I see only 2 positive and 3 negative votes for question 1

Comment: @JimMacaulay question 1 has as answers 2,3 and 7 if you look at Answer table. So we look at Vote table with PubId = 1, 2, 3 and 7. That gives us 4 N and 3 P

Comment: @GordonLinoff pubId refers to QId from Question table or RId from Answer table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`s combined with `CASE` to compute the scores. For example:

```
select
  *
from (
  select
    q.qid,
    sum(case when v.type = 'P' then 1 
             when v.type = 'N' then -1 else 0 end
       ) as score
  from question q
  left join answer a on a.qid = q.qid
  left join vote v on v.pubid = a.rid
  group by q.qid
) x
order by score desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . assuming that `pubid` matches `rid`, this is basically just conditional aggregation:

```
select a.qid,
       sum(type = 'P') - sum(type = 'N') as score
from answer a join
     vote v
     on v.pubid = r.rid
group by a.qid;
```

EDIT based on coment:

```
select q.qid,
       coalesce(sum(type = 'P'), 0) - coalesce(sum(type = 'N'), 0) as score
from question q left join
     answer a
     on q.qid = a.quid left join
     vote v
     on v.pubid = r.rid
group by q.qid
order by score desc;
```

Comment: thank you for your response. by executing this, we don't take in consideration that question with QId 9 has score 0. No positive or negative vote. We only take in condieration the questions that have answers and not questions without answers like question with QId 9

Comment: @Mohammadreza . . . That is not clear from your question.  But I'm adding the modification which I think is a simple solution.