# getting the score of each question in a database

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, max, sql-order-by

I have a data base like this:
Question table:

```
QId | Title
----------
1   | SR
4   | TR
9   | AA
```

Answer table:

```
RId | QId
----------
2   | 1
3   | 1
5   | 4
6   | 4
7   | 1
8   | 4
```

and Vote table:

```
PubId | Type
-------------
1     | P
1     | P
1     | P
1     | N
2     | N
2     | N
3     | P
4     | N
4     | N
5     | N
6     | P
```

QId in Answer table references QId of Question table and OubId in Vote table reference QId from Question table or RId from Answer table.
I am somewhat new to sql and after a lot of trying, i did not get what i wanted.
So what I want is to show questions ordered by their score. Score of every question in Question table is the best score of that question and its answers. And the score is calculated by difference between positive votes and negative votes of that question or answer.
For example the score of question 1 is 2 because the best score in question one and its answers (2,3,7) is the score of the question itself which is 3-1=2. Or for example the score of question 4 is 1 because the score of answer 6 to this question is 1 which is better than other answers and the question 4 itself.
So the result would look like something like this: 1, 4, 9.
For now I have only the code blew which just shows every question or answer with the votes that it has.

```
select v.PubId, v.Type from
(select r.RId from Answer r
UNION 
SELECT q.QId from Question q
) as a 
left join Vote v on a.RId=v.PubId 
where v.PubId is not null
```

Comment: this doen't make much sense, to be honest, you got question --> answers--> vote it is a clear relation ship, so the union between questions and answers make not that much sense

Comment: @nbk I do a union to take in consideration of the votes for question itself

Comment: The tables should be Questions(Quid, title)  Answers(Rid,Quid Votes (Rid,type) the same names represent the relationship, so you know every vote to every Response to every question

Comment: How is this question different from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61988086/how-to-sum-and-group-a-table-by-a-specific-column) you've asked earlier?

Comment: @mkrieger1the difference is that there we are calculating the score of every question as diiference between the sum of all positive votes and the sum of all negative votes for every question and its answers. But here we caculute the score of every question and its answers sepratly and we choose the best score among these to represent the score of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table structures are quite counter-intuitive, since you are apparently sharing a primary key column across the questions and answers table.

You can, however, do what you want with `union all`, a `left join`, and two levels of aggregation:

```
select qid, max(score) score
from (
    select x.qid, x.pubid, sum(type = 'P') - sum(type = 'N') score
    from (
        select qid, qid pubid from questions
        union all
        select qid, rid from answers
    ) x
    left join votes v on v.pubid = x.pubid
    group by x.qid, x.pubid
) t
group by qid
order by score desc
```

The subquery computes the score of each question and answer, while keeping track of the relationship between them. Then, the outer query selects the top score per question.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=13a50038017e75178bd5850e7c0a8a14)**:

```
qid | score
--: | ----:
  1 |     2
  4 |     1
  9 |  null
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried to do it in another way but my query is way way longer than yours and yours is better and more readble. Just a side note, I am using DB browser for sqlite to test this queries and the thing is that there I have 1 for question 1. Itried on other platform like the demo you put and it works fine there. So could this be an intern problem with DB browser for sqlite ?